# Trouble using indexOf on a complex array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [indexOf method in an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array)

I have a javascript array which follows this format:

```
var arrayName = [
{id: "a", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"},
{id: "b", gender: "woman", item: "stuff"},
{id: "c", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"},
{id: "d", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"}
];
```

Is there a way that I can use array.indexOf to find an index in the array, when for example I know the "id" variable.

For example I tried;

```
var position = arrayName.indexOf("b");
arrayName[position].gender = "man"
```

At the moment I am using;

```
for(var i=0; i<arrayName.length; i++) {
   if(arrayName[i].id == "b"){
       arrayName[i].gender = "man";
   }
}
```

This second technique works but the actual array I am using has 150 entries and 10 items in each entry so looping through it all seems very wasteful when I know the "id" of the entry I want to edit. indexOf would be a much cleaner approach if I can get it working.

Comment: Calling indexOf on an array is not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @erturne - you're right - it's not even in IE8 - wow

Comment: @erturne: It is not, but [as stated on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), it can be easily implemented even in older / deprecated browsers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your call to `indexOf` is checking the objects in your array against the string `b`, which will never work.

Looping through the array elements to find the right id is a simple solution.

Or, you could make your own indexOf function:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfId = function(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if (this[i].id === id)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

    var arrayName = [
      { id: "a", gender: "man", item: "stuff" },
      { id: "b", gender: "woman", item: "stuff" },
      { id: "c", gender: "man", item: "stuff" },
      { id: "d", gender: "man", item: "stuff" }];

    var position = arrayName.indexOfId("b");

    alert(position);  //alerts 1
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvqVB/)

**EDIT**

If you want to compare your array elements to any property, here's how you do it (note that I'm using [] syntax to get an arbitrary property)

```
    Array.prototype.indexOfField = function (propertyName, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
            if (this[i][propertyName] === value)
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    var position = arrayName.indexOfField("id", "b");
    alert(position);  //alerts 1

    position = arrayName.indexOfField("gender", "man");
    alert(position); //alerts 0
```

---

Or, if you don't want to mess with Array's prototype, and you don't mind using features not present in older browsers, you could use Array's `filter` function

```
var position = arrayName.indexOf(arrayName.filter(function (val) {
      return val.id === "b";
})[0]);
```

Note that this function is not present in IE8, and so to support this browser you'd have to grab the [shim from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**EDIT** - oops, indexOf isn't friendly toward old browsers either.  If you opt for this second bit of code and wanted to support IE, you'd also have to grab the shim for indexOf [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Thanks Adam, that is what I suspected. I will probably go ahead and use a variation of your prototype.indexOfId technique as these kind of edits are quite common so it will be cleaner to reference to one single prototype function. My variation will probably be to:

    Array.prototype.indexOfId = function(variable,value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
            if (this[i].variable === value)
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

This way I can use it to search for more than just the "id" variable E.g. if I wanted to edit the "id" based on the "gender".

Comment: @user1121506 - that won't work - stand by for another edit

Comment: @user1121506 - edited - the code in your comment was 99.9% correct, you just needed a little tweak.

Comment: Works brilliantly, thanks Adam and everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the opportunity to, you can use Array.prototype.filter:

```
var arrayName = [
    {id: "a", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"},
    {id: "b", gender: "woman", item: "stuff"},
    {id: "c", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"},
    {id: "d", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"}
];

console.log(arrayName.filter(function(i) {
    return i.id === 'b';
}));
```

Which will give:

```
[ { id: 'b', gender: 'woman', item: 'stuff' } ]
```

Comment: What if I want to find the index and remove the element ?

Comment: Simply `return i.id !== 'b';` instead.

Answer (score -1):

you can override `indexOf` using `prototype`

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        if (this[i].id === elem)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

var arrayName = [
{id: "a", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"},
{id: "b", gender: "woman", item: "stuff"},
{id: "c", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"},
{id: "d", gender: "man",   item: "stuff"}
];

alert(arrayName.indexOf("b"));
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r8rp9/1/