# Finding the index position of an array inside an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

```
var a = [[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]];
```

If I want to find the index position of `[0,0]`? How can that be done in **JavaScript**?

I checked a few places and **indexOf** function but it doesn't work with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8670345/2902660

Comment: You might want to read about references and values in JavaScript. **indexOf** and all other functions that operates on generic objects will do comparison by reference. Two boxes contain the same numbers, but they aren't the same box.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hashmap of the indices and access that

```js
var a = [[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]],

b = a.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
  a[c] = i;
  return a;      
},{});

console.log('Index of [0,0] is ' +b[ [0,0] ] )
```

Comment: @Pineda run the code and look at what it logs

Comment: apologies, still trying to get my head around why this works.  It's darn sweet though and have no idea as to why it's down voted

Comment: @Pineda because the arrays are implicitly cast to string when used as object properties

Comment: Blimey, so a hashmap is effectively an object whose properties act as access keys that hold a certain value, in this case the index of their position.  This would break if there were duplicates in the array though, since the index returned would that of the last instance of it in the array...

Comment: All due respect, this is a *terrible* idea. It relies on the side-effect of turning an array into a string when you use the array as a property name, and thus is both inefficient and only useful for a very, very narrow range of use cases (this *is* one of them, but there are very few). At the very, very, very least, this answer needs an explanation of what it's doing, why it will fail in most cases, and why it works in this specific case.

Comment: Some browsers don't support the `reduce` method use this [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:  By side-effect, are you talking in regards to functional purity or do you mean the **quirk** of the array implicitly being cast to string?  I ask mainly because if it is the former, isn't it the case that for all inputs, it would output the the same hashmap?

Comment: @Pineda: I'm not at all sure I understand your question. But for instance searching for `["a","a"]` in `[["a","b"],["a","b"],["a","a"],["a,a"]]` would return the wrong index with the above technique.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:  I was thinking in terms of the term 'side-effect' in terms of functional programming and 'pure' functions.  I do see how the solution is specific but hadn't seen a hashmap created this way before.

Comment: @Pineda: Ah, I see; no, I wasn't using the term side-effect in the functional programming sense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: ok, cool.  Thanks for pointing out the cons of this solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for outer iteration and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for inner iteration and check the length and the items.

```js
var array = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0]],
    find = [0, 0],
    index = -1;

array.some(function (a, i) {
    if (a.length === find.length && a.every(function (b, j) { return b === find[j]; })) {
        index = i;
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(index);
```

Comment: You really should just dupehammer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8670345/2902660 (I can't because I was silly enough to vote it as unclear early on). *(not my dv, btw -- unlike many of the other answers here :-) Yours is the only decent solution here )*

Answer (score 0):

***Fast***(in terms of performance) solution using `while` loop and `Array.prototype.every()` function:

```js
var a = [[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]], len = a.length,
        search_item = [0,1], pos = -1;

while (len--) {
    if ((a[len].length === search_item.length) 
            && a[len].every(function(el, i){ return el == search_item[i]; })) {
        pos = len;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(pos);
```

[***Array.prototype.every()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)