# jquery get index of object where field is equal to value

Tags: jquery

I have an array with objects. The objects have a property name. 
I want the index of the object where the property is equal to bart. How can i find the index of that object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array

Comment: is there no other option than write a loop?

Comment: If they were actually HTML elements under a single element you could do `index = $('#parentobject').index('[property="bart"]')`

Comment: @TrueBlueAusie this was actually the answer i was looking for , thanks, you may ad it as an answer to this post too

Comment: Have added as answer... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they were actually HTML elements under a single element you could do

```
index = $('#parentobject').index('[property="bart"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [{ name: 'bart' }, { name: 'baz' }];

function getPropIndexByName(data, prop, str){

    var ret = []; //updated to handle multiple indexes

    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        if(v[prop] === str)
            ret.push(k);
    });

    return ret.length ? ret : null;
}

var result = getPropIndexByName(data,   //data source
                               'name',  //property name
                               'bart'); //property value

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Le72k/1/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for (var key in myobject)
{
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: for or foreach it is?

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = jQuery.grep(array, function() {
    // this is a reference to the element in the array
    // you can do any test on it you want
    // return true if you want it to be in the resulting matches array
    // return false if you don't want it to be in the resulting matches array

    // for example: to find objects with the Amount property set to a certain value
    return(this.Amount === 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had:

```
var myArray = [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}];
```

To get the index of the first object where `x === 2` I would do:

```
function indexOfFirstMatch (arr, condition) {
    var i = 0;

    for(;i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(condition(arr[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

var index = indexOfFirstMatch(myArray, function (item) { return item.x === 2; });
// => 1
```

If you wanted to be a real maverick, you could extend Array:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfFirstMatch = function indexOfFirstMatch (condition) {
    var i = 0;

    for(;i < this.length; i++) {
        if(condition(this[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

var index = myArray.indexOfFirstMatch(function (item) { return item.x === 2; });
// => 1
```