# How to vertically align a list on one item, with HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML document with a very long list, like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>frog</li>
    <li>fish</li>
    <li>flamingo</li>
    <li>ferret</li>
    <li><div class="marked">fox</div></li>
    ...
</ol>
```

The list is too long for all items to be visible on the screen. I've marked one item with `div class="marked">` and `</div>`. Is there some way to vertically center the list on that marked item.

- If the list is too long, it should run off the edge of the visible screen, with no scrollbars created.

Here is an example of how it appears in the browser window:

```
 __________________
|   2.fish         |
|   3.flamingo     |
|   4.ferret       | <-- This marked item is centered.
|   5.elephant     |
|___6.mouse________| <-- No scrollbars.
```

How can I vertically align a list on a marketed item?

Comment: This question is a lot of math. I'm working on an answer, but it has taken way longer than I thought it would.

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution based on James G.'s code, which avoids the loop by using `getBoundingClientRect()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/d8d5jjvc/4/

```
var list = document.getElementById('list'),
    marked= document.getElementById('marked'),
    crm= marked.getBoundingClientRect(),
    height= crm.bottom-crm.top;

list.scrollTop= (crm.top-height)-(list.clientHeight-height)/2;
```

Comment: Cool. What a useful function, TIL.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I really hope I understood you correctly, because this took WAY longer than I expected.

[Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryyj9b3n/2/)

First you have to find the element you're centering on, the list, the height of the items in the list, and the index of the element you're centering on. (I stole a function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array) to do that last bit, as well as changing your class to an id. You can figure that out if it needs to be a class)

```
function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm) {
            for(var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (myArray[i].firstChild === searchTerm) return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }

var list = document.getElementById('list'),
            listItems = list.children,
            listItemHeight = list.scrollHeight / listItems.length,
            target = elem,
            index = arrayObjectIndexOf(listItems, target);
```

Then the tricky part was the math. First we get the height of elements above the element we're centering on, then we subtract the height of the container, minus the item we're centering on, over 2. If that makes any sense. You might want to draw it if you don't understand the math, it'll make more sense on paper.

```
list.scrollTop = (index * listItemHeight) - ((list.clientHeight - listItemHeight) / 2);
```

Comment: Nice work.  You can avoid the loop by using `getBoundingClientRect`.  See my post.

Answer (score -1):

You display a list vertically with the display option.

```
display: inline;
```

I usually use the inline-block parameter, this is

```
display: inline-block;
```

Then, you've to do this on your css.

```
.marked: { display: inline-block; }
```

I hope this works for you.