# How to correctly use JavaScript indexOf in a date array

Tags: javascript, date, indexof

Here is the code:

```
var collection = [new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 24)];
var d=new Date(2014, 11, 24);

var idx= collection.indexOf(d);
```

I guess the variable `idx` should have a value of `1` since it is the second value in the array `collection`. But it turns out to be `-1`.

Why is that? Is there any special thing for the JavaScript `Date` type I need to pay attention?

Here is a snippet:

```js
(function() {

  var collection = [new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 24)];
  var d = new Date(2014, 11, 24);

  var idx1 = collection.indexOf(d);

  var intArray = [1, 3, 4, 5];
  var idx2 = intArray.indexOf(4);

  $('#btnTry1').on('click', function() {
    $('#result1').val(idx1);
  });

  $('#btnTry2').on('click', function() {
    $('#result2').val(idx2);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Index:
<input type="text" id="result1" value="">
<button id="btnTry1">Find index in a date array</button>
<br />Index:
<input type="text" id="result2" value="">
<button id="btnTry2">Find index in a regular array</button>
```

Comment: `d` is a new instance of Date, and even though the date is the same as index 1, the objects are different, hence the result being -1.

Comment: Two different instances are never equal to each other. FYI, ES6 solves this by introducing [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), which accepts a callback for comparison: `collection.findIndex(function(x) { return x.valueOf() === d.valueOf(); });`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Two *Objects* will never be equal unless you serialise them. Lucky, *Date* is pretty easy to serialise as an integer.

```
var collection = [new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 24)],
    d = new Date(2014, 11, 24),
    idx;

idx = collection.map(Number).indexOf(+d); // 1
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^ serialisation steps
```

Comment: Neat! Your `map` and the `+d` are eye-opening for me.

Comment: Supposing the Dates were in an array of objects like  `data = [{ date: Date 2018-09-15T00:00:00.000Z, pn: 55, other: "blah" },...]` how would the map and such translate?

Answer (score 8):

Two different objects are never equal to each other, even if they have the same properties / values. Here is a forward looking answer to the problem:

ECMAScript 6 introduces [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which accepts a comparison callback:

```
var index = collection.findIndex(function(x) { 
    return x.valueOf() === d.valueOf(); 
});
```

[Browser support isn't great yet though.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf()` won't work here... It's been well explained in the previous answers...

You'd be able to create your own lookup for the index. Here's a simple example comparing the dates using their `.getTime()` value...

```js
(function() {

  var collection = [new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 24)];
  var d = new Date(2014, 11, 24);

  var idx1 = -1;
  collection.forEach(function(item, index){
    if(d.getTime() == item.getTime())
      idx1 = index;
  });

  var intArray = [1, 3, 4, 5];
  var idx2 = intArray.indexOf(4);

  $('#btnTry1').on('click', function() {
    $('#result1').val(idx1);
  });

  $('#btnTry2').on('click', function() {
    $('#result2').val(idx2);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Index:
<input type="text" id="result1" value="">
<button id="btnTry1">Find index in a date array</button>
<br />Index:
<input type="text" id="result2" value="">
<button id="btnTry2">Find index in a regular array</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your "d" object is the different object. In other words:

```
var d = new Date(2014, 11, 24);

d === new Date(2014, 11, 24); // returns false
```

You can try this:

```
var d = new Date(2014, 11, 24);
var collection = [new Date(2014, 11, 25), d];

var idx = collection.indexOf(d); // returns 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand why. But what is the correct way to see if a date value is contained in the array?

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.indexOfDate = function(date){
   for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
      if (+this[i] === +date) return i;
   };
   return -1;
};

// then 
var idx1 = collection.indexOfDate(d);
```