# Javascript indexOf in date array always resulting -1

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, vue.js

I'm facing a problem checking whether a date is in my array or not.

I refer to this article [How to correctly use JavaScript indexOf in a date array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450867/how-to-correctly-use-javascript-indexof-in-a-date-array)

But when I use it in my project, it always results in -1.

Here's my code

```
for (var current = dateStart; current <= dateEnd; current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1)) {
    console.log(this.leaveState.currentHoliday.map(Number).indexOf(+current));
}
```

I need to check whether `current` date is in `currentHoliday` array or not.

Comment: Please add your input array

Comment: Sees like an inefficient way to check for a holiday, converts the entire holiday array on each iteration. Why not iterate over the holiday array once and see if there are any values between the start and end Dates? If the holidays are sorted, you can stop looking as soon as the holiday is after the end date.

Comment: @RobG so i need 2 loop? nested? is that more efficient than my way?

Comment: there may be issue of format

Comment: Could you make a working snippet with your relevant HTML, JavaScript, datepickers, and whatever?

Comment: @DeepakKumar I already print current date and each item in array.. it showsthe exact same format

Comment: @TakitIsy mmm how to make that? actually i'm never use tools like that here .-.

Comment: No, you just need one loop. You are converting the entire array of dates to number on every iteration, and if you have a range of 30 days you'll do 30 iterations (and convert all the dates to number 30 times).

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if we could see the array you're asking about matching.  What are the contents of `this.leaveState.currentHoliday`?

Answer (score 0):

I think mapping doesn't require to loop into your array.
and -1 is somehow mean that the date does not exist in your array.

Maybe because in every loop you add a day to it before you see the actual day.

I think you could try:

```
    var alldays = [...];
    //you should eliminate these two codes
//    datestart = something;
//  dateend = something;
    var holiday;
    for(var i in alldays){
           console.log(alldays.map(Number).indexOf(this.leaveState.currentHoliday));
    }
```

Comment: since I use datepicker to choose startdate and enddate, i think i requires more work put all the date between start and end date to an array..

Comment: Hi. Please also take a look at this post which touches on Javascript loops https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/1219213