# Using 2 arrays of objects, iterate over them using something similar to IndexOf (or other option)

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, i was trying to iterate over.  The array is pretty simple in format.

```
{a:5, b:"key", c:19}
```

i was trying to compare an array with a subset, say:  [{a:5},...]

```
for (var i = 0; i < subset.length; i++) {
    var searchTerm = subset[i].a;

    var index = objs.indexOf(searchTerm, function (el) {
        return el.a;
    });

    if (index > -1) {
        objs[index].Found = true;
    }
}
```

So that way ultimately objs, could have a new key in it, 'Found'

This way, it will set the main array `objs` item.Found = true, if it existed in subset.

There are 2 issues though.  Accounting for multiple instances of the same item, and the fact that this current implementation doesnt seem to work.

This is a slight expansion of ([indexOf method in an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array) )but with an array of search terms.

ideally, i dont want to change the arrays at all, so im trying not to slice, etc.

In a lot of the defintions, indexOf is defined as:

```
function indexOf (key, start);
```

instead of the ideas i am trying to work with.

**Edit**

Here is some code that i have to get this working, but i was thinking there is a more effecient way to do it than written.

```
for (var j = 0; j < compare.length; j++){
  var searchTerm = compare[j]["a"];
  for (var k = 0; k < objs.length; k++){
      if (!objs[k].Found && objs[k]["a"] == searchTerm){
           objs[k].Found = true;
          break;
      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What if more than one object matches?

Comment: Since when does `indexOf` take a function as a second argument?

Comment: @Adam It doesn't. If I understand it correctly, the question is how to do something like this.

Comment: There's a ton of methods you can use on `Arrays` that take callbacks: `map`, `some`, `every`, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: One of the answers in the linked item, had used a defined function, I was trying to find something more effecient then what i am about to submit as an edit

Comment: @Fallenreaper - the most up-voted answer in the linked question uses `map`

Comment: @Fallenreaper Even if there was an overload of `indexOf` that worked like this, internally it would have to iterate over the second array. With regard to efficiency, in your case there are still 2 arrays that have to be looped over...

Comment: @Adam I mustve scrolled passed that.  I did not see the map option.

Comment: That looks like an object, not an array.

Comment: i guess i could just do something like that answer then.  create 2 maps and walk those instead of walking 2 arrays of objects.  Then you consume a bit more memory, though this is negligible in the cases i am running against (less than 500).  With an additional loop, doing a .map().indexOf() on each iteration is just absurd

Comment: I don't think it can get any more efficient than the example in your edit. There are a lot of ways in JS to refactor this, but I don't think you're ever going to beat `array1.length * array2.length` iterations.

Comment: thats what i thought.  Damn.  Ok.  Thanks @jwatts1980