# Removing an element from an array of Object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, indexof

I'm building a live notification system with Meteor, but as I've never done this before, I'm certainly tricking to get something that works.

I have a `<ul>` list of notifications. I defined an event clicking on the `<a class="notif-link">` that each `<li>` contains.

My notifications have an ID, a type, and some other stuff we do not care about.

```
notifications:
    [
         {id: 0, type: 0, img: null, link: "/profile"},
         {id: 1, type: 1, img: null, link: "/profile"},
         {id: 2, type: 2, img: null, link: "/profile"},
         {id: 3, type: 3, img: null, link: "/profile"},
    ]
```

...

```
Template.navigation.events({
       "click .notif-link": function(e, tmpl){
           console.log(EJSON.stringify(this)); // print the verbosed notification object as shown above
           var index = Meteor.user().profile.notifications.indexOf({id: this.id});
           console.log(index); // always == -1
           newNotifArray = Meteor.user().profile.notifications.splice(index, 1);
           Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {'profile.notifications': newNotifArray}});
       }
   });
```

The `notification.id` is set as the `<a>` `#id`, which should allow me to identify the notification in the array and delete it when the link is clicked.

The problem is that `notification.indexOf({id : this.id})` always return me -1.
I guess the problem is that I do not know how to work properly on an array of objects.

Can someone explain to me how to deal with it ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an object called: `{id: 1}`, but your notification entries are larger. They contain other fields as well (not just an ID field). You're mixing up standard JavaScript comparison with MongoDB queries.

Have a look at [MongoDBs $pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operation. Something like:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId}, { $pull: {
    'profile.notifications': { id: this.id },
}});
```

(I haven't tested this code, not entirely sure about the `id: this.id` query..)

Loading the data into memory, modifying it there and then writing it back might seem intuitive (I did the same thing at first^^), but operating directly on the database is a) more efficient and b) much more elegant.

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for, but using it, the console throw me errors : 

mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create  --> meteor.js:533:6

Error : meteor.js:532:14

The second one seems to be related to error throwing in firefox

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your attempting to find the index of an new object you created: `{id: this.id}`, inside the array of notifications objects you defined, which obviously does not include it.

`Array.IndexOf` when given an object to search for, will attempt to find the same object (pointer in memory) in the array, so you can't really use it unless you have the actual object.
For instance: `notifications.indexOf({id: 0, type: 0, img: null, link: "/profile"})`, will also return -1 since its a different object even though has the same values.

I am not familiar with Meteor, but there are libraries that can help you in this cases, for example underscore is very helpful for array and list helpers.
For this case you can use underscores's [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) method like so:

```
_.notifications.findWhere({id: this.id})
```

This will return the actual object in the array which matches the attributes you specified, with the actual object you can then use `Array.indexOf` to get the index of the object inside the array.

I'm sure that are a lot of other ways and libraries to do this, depends on what you are already using.
Here are some links to additional solutions not using underscore:

using pure Javascript map - [indexOf method in an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array)

using JQuery grep - [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was thinking that indexOf is waiting for an int to look for a precise address in the memory, but JS being a really high-leve language, I hoped it might include several algorithms depending on the parameter.