# array.indexOf in TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

**UPDATE: Although this question is marked as duplicated with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array). But @ssube's way is neat and much smarter.**

**UPDATE2: Seems there is new way to do it in the comment by @Grungondola.**

I am using Typescript.

This works well.

```
var array1 = [];
array1.push(5);
array1.push(6);
console.log("a", array2.indexOf(6));
```

But this does not work well. Because array2.indexOf returns -1 which means it does not find it.

```
var array2 = [];
array2.push({aa:5,bb:5});
array2.push({aa:6,bb:6});
console.log(array2.indexOf({aa:6,bb:6}));
```

Looks like indexOf does not support Object. Does TypeScript have its own ways to deal with this kind of problem? Thanks.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with TypeScript. In JavaScript two objects are never `equal`. You'll have to write a custom search.

Comment: `indexOf()` is a method for objects of type String, not Array

Comment: Sorry, I'm mistaken. There are an `indexOf()` for arrays : https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf . Thousands of sorrys :(

Comment: As of es2015, there is a function on arrays called `findIndex` that accepts a predicate in the same way as `find` and would allow you to do a deep search for the object that you want. I would provide this as an answer, but answering is not possible any more. The problem with this is that it lacks support in IE for some reason, but there is a polyfill that you can add for that:

[findIndex Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: If the purpose is just to know if an element exists refer to array.some

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No. The problem is not with `Object`, but that you are creating two different objects.

The object literal syntax (`{foo: 'bar'}`) declares an object inline. When the script is executed, the object is created. Using that syntax multiple times *creates multiple objects*.

You can easily test that with `{foo: 3} === {foo: 3}`. This will evaluate to false, but they are not the same object (reference).

The `indexOf` method checks if the object, string, number, etc, is present in the array. You're passing a new object, which is not in the array.

If you have a reference to the object, you can use that and `indexOf` will work:

```
var foo = {aa:5,bb:5}, bar = {aa:6,bb:6};
var array2 = [];
array2.push(foo);
array2.push(bar);
console.log(array2.indexOf(foo));
```

Because you're referring to the same instance, this will print the index.

You can also use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with a predicate to perform a deep search:

```
function deepIndexOf(arr, obj) {
  return arr.findIndex(function (cur) {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(function (key) {
      return obj[key] === cur[key];
    });
  });
}

var array2 = [];
array2.push(foo);
array2.push(bar);
console.log(deepIndexOf(array2, foo));
```

This won't recurse into nested objects, but will accomplish the comparison you're looking for (equivalence on two objects and their immediate fields).

Comment: Premature optimization et cetera, but this could be optimized. At least, getting the `keys` and `values` from `arr` before the loop... And where are those nice arrow functions? They could maximize the simplicity to its half ;)