# Sum specific array values depends on list of index value on other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
a = [12, 50, 2, 5, 6];
```

and

```
b = [0, 1, 3];
```

I want to sum those arrays value in array `A` with exact index value as array `B` so that would be `12+50+5 = 67`. Kindly help me to do this in native javascript. I already tried searching but I can't find any luck. I found related article below,  but I can't get the logic

[indexOf method in an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array)

Comment: index 3 value is not 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do as follows;

```js
var arr = [12, 50, 2, 5, 6],
    idx = [0, 1, 3],
    sum = idx.map(i => arr[i])
             .reduce((p,c) => p + c);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sumAIndiciesOfB = function (a, b) {
    var runningSum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; b.length; i++) {
        runningSum += a[b[i]];
    }
    return runningSum;
};
```

logic explained:

loop through array b. For each value in b, look it up in array a (`a[b[i]]`) and then add it to `runningSum`. After looping through b you will have summed each index of `a` and the total will be in `runningSum`.

Comment: This works, but keep in mind that assigning a function to a variable forces all your function calls to come after assignment, which is not true of functions that are not assigned to variables.

Answer (score 2):

`b` contains the indices of `a` to sum, so loop over `b`, referencing `a`:

```
var sum=0, i;
for (i=0;i<b.length;i++)
{
  sum = sum + a[b[i]];
}
// sum now equals your result
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply reduce array `a` and only add values if their index exists in array `b`.

```
a.reduce((prev, curr, index) => b.indexOf(index) >= 0 ? prev+curr : prev, 0)
```

The result is 12+50+5=67.

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
function addByIndexes(numberArray, indexArray){
  var n = 0;
  for(var i=0,l=indexArray.length; i<l; i++){
    n += numberArray[indexArray[i]];
  }
  return n;
}
console.log(addByIndexes([12, 50, 2, 5, 6], [0, 1, 3]));
```