# Type-/JavaScript - array.indexOf always returns -1

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I use the the `splice` function to delete an element from an array and the `indexOf` function to get the elements position.

But `indexOf` returns always `-1`, although the same element is in the array.

MyCode(Angular2):

```
subToDelete : Subscription;
public unsubscribe(topic:string) {
    this.subToDelete = new Subscription(topic);
    console.log("DeleteIndex: ",this.subs.indexOf(this.subToDelete));
    this.subs.splice(this.subs.indexOf(this.subToDelete),1);
    console.log("SubTo Delete: ",this.subToDelete);
    this.subs.forEach(element => {
    console.log("Subscribed to: ",element);
    });
}
```

This is the console output, where you can see, that the element that should be deleted, is included in the array, but the `indexOf` returns `-1` nevertheless.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfh4N.jpg   (somehow I cant upload a photo, so here is the link)

Comment: Since your array seems to store objects and `indexOf` checks for strict equality your `new Subscription(topic)` can never be equal to an already existing array element (as you just created a new object which was not in the array before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because you are trying to search within an object array. This is not the same as an array of literals.

You can do something like this

```
pos = this.subs.map(function(e) {
    return e.topic;
  })
  .indexOf(this.subToDelete.topic);

this.subs.splice(pos,1);
```

take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8668174/1754020) for more information on the topic.

Comment: indexOf will return -1 if the topic does not exist, thus splice will then remove the last element from subs. You need to protect the splice operation with if (pos > -1)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which requires les iterations than the `map` function:

```
let index: number;
this.subs.find((item, i) => { if (item.topic === topic) index = i });
this.subs.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: what does find return?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which I think is the easiest solution:

```
let index = this.subs.findIndex((item) => item.topic === topic);
if (index > -1) this.subs.splice(index, 1);
```