# Splice is not working for the object(indexOf is not a function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, splice

I have an object like

```
Object {val1: "Hello", val2: "", dt1: "pilo1", dt2: "pilo2", lo1: "log1"}
```

Now i want to remove those keys that have empty values ("").

I tried the code:

```
 angular.forEach($scope.test,function(value,key){
          if(value==""){
                    var index = $scope.test.indexOf(key);
                    $scope.test.splice(index,1);
          }
  });
//$scope.test={val1: "Hello",val2: "",dt1:".......}
```

Now there is one more thing that i have to consider **the keys are not static**. **They can change their name depends on the condition**. For eg: `{val1: "",val2:"Hello1",val3:"",val4:"Hello3",dt1:""}`
So i need a generic solution.

Comment: indexOf is for arrays... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete an object property using the `splice` method. Instead of doing this, you can use the `delete` operator.

```
angular.forEach($scope.test,function(value,key){
    if(value==""){
        delete $scope.test[key]
    }
});
```

For further info regardng this operator, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Below I have a snippet with *plain JavaScript*, that shows the use of `delete` operator.

```js
var obj = {val1: "Hello", val2: "", dt1: "pilo1", dt2: "pilo2", lo1: "log1"};
console.log('Before we call delete');
console.log(obj);
Object.keys(obj)
      .forEach(function(key){
          if(obj[key]===""){
              delete obj[key];
          }
});
console.log('After we call delete');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It's woking fine. Thanks :)