# How to pre-select a default option in ng-options using $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-scope, ng-options, ng-init

I have a `<select>` in a form with other fields, like so-

```
<form class="formCSS">
  <div class="inputs">
   <label class="labelTag">Name *: &nbsp&nbsp</label>
   <select class="inputTag" ng-model="selectedName" 
           ng-options="n.name for n in adminNames"></select>
  </div>
</form>
```

`adminChannels` is an object array of this structure `{_id:"....", name:"..."}`

When I "transitionTo" this state, I pass a name (which exists in adminNames too) like so -

```
$state.go('schedule',{name:response.name});
```

I want the said name (accessed using `$scope.name`) to be pre-selected when this template loads.

I tried something like this -
`ng-init = "selectedName=adminNames[adminNames.indexOf(name)]"`

I do get the auto-populated drop-down menu but nothing gets selected as default.

I went through all other posts about selecting default options, none of them provide info about pre-selecting using $scope variable.

Please let me know if I've to provide any more info/code. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
$scope.selectedName = $scope.adminNames.find( x => (x.name == $scope.name));
```

The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

---

Another approach is to use the `as` clause in the `ng-options` directive:

```
<select class="inputTag" ng-model="selectedName" 
        ng-options="n.name as n.name for n in adminNames">
</select>
```

The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.adminNames=[
        {name: "fred"},
        {name: "jane"},
        {name: "sally"},
    ];
    $scope.selectedName="jane";
    $scope.find = function(name) {
         return $scope.adminNames.find( x => (x.name == name)); 
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select class="inputTag" ng-model="selectedName" 
            ng-options="n.name as n.name for n in adminNames">
    </select>
    <br>
    object = {{find(selectedName)}}
</body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it out but got "$scope.selectedName = undefined" when I console.log -ed it, though. I was able to achieve what I wanted using the `map` function as described in the answer below.
The demo and the link are helpful. Since I'm getting the name from the url, the demo doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

When I started debugging stage-by-stage, I saw that `adminNames[adminNames.indexOf(name)]` was "undefined".

So I did this in the controller instead, to find the index of the $scope.name that is received -

`var index = $scope.adminNames.map(function(e) 
                { return e.name; }).indexOf($scope.name);`

`$scope.selectedName = $scope.adminNames[index];`

This [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array) helped me figure this out.