# How to fetch data from object without using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

This is the structure which is saved in the database. I want to fetch only "**entityInfo**" directly without using any loop.

```
let x = {
    "12": [{
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:29:59.999Z"
        },
        {
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:49:25.000Z",

        },
        {
            "entityInfo": [{
                "entityName": "acd",
                "timeSpent": 0.028055555555555556
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: x.12.[0].entityInfo 

Comment: `x.12[0].entityInfo`?

Comment: `x['12'][2].entityInfo` ? :p

Comment: self['x']['12']['2']['entityInfo'] ;P

Comment: but, why no loop?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the first item in the `12` array which has an `entityInfo` value, then you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
let x = {
    "12": [{
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:29:59.999Z"
        },
        {
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:49:25.000Z",

        },
        {
            "entityInfo": [{
                "entityName": "acd",
                "timeSpent": 0.028055555555555556
            }]
        }
    ]
}

console.log(x["12"].find(a => a.entityInfo))
```

Comment: I am sure `.find` wraps a loop inside its implementation

Comment: True. But I think OP means a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map() function encapsulated. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array).
But you have to question yourself if an array makes sense here.

Comment: `.map` traverse through the padded array like a loop

Comment: I think he looks for something looking cleaner than a loop. @GeorgeBailey

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = {
    "12": [{
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:29:59.999Z"
        },
        {
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:49:25.000Z",

        },
        {
            "entityInfo": [{
                "entityName": "acd",
                "timeSpent": 0.028055555555555556
            }]
        }
    ]
}
// will return a value if the entityInfo object exists
var ans = x["12"].filter((val)=>{return val.entityInfo})[0]
console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there only is one entityInfo you can use the following to get the first element that has a "entityInfo" property.

```js
x["12"].find(i => i.entityInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` for getting the values and then `find` for finding all the entity info objects

```js
var x = {
    "12": [{
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:29:59.999Z"
        },
        {
            "entity": {
                "id": "40ea18e6-f898-414a-96fd-b3ef5a0eb7cd"
            },
            "startTime": "2018-12-19T06:49:25.000Z",

        },
        {
            "entityInfo": [{
                "entityName": "acd",
                "timeSpent": 0.028055555555555556
            }]
        }
    ]
};

console.log(Object.values(x).flat().find(el => el.entityInfo));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches and possible solutions to this question.
You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) , [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach).
But each of the loop over elements internally, the other approach is if you know the position of entityInfo in x["12"] and you want to safe read it. Then you can use utilities like [these](https://gist.github.com/ashish-r/91ee6ad307687061b765dcf32de40589).