# Get index of searchresult in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```js
var member_data_list = [
  ["adrian", "test", Number(9)],
  ["supler", "test", Number(2.3)],
  ["franz", "test", Number(2.5)],
  ["drucker", "test", Number(9.6)],
];

if (exists(member_data_list, "franz")) {
     //HERE I NEED TO GET THE INDEX OF MEMBER_DATA_LIST[?]
     //EXAMPLE: if (exists(member_data_list, "franz")) => RESULT => 2 (MEMBER_DATA_LIST[2])
     console.log("NAME IS IN ARRAY AT INDEX " + "?");
}
        
function exists(arr, search) {
   return arr.some(row => row.includes(search));
}
```

How to get the index of the name in this array?

Comment: You'll have to use a loop like `forEach` which returns the index of the loop. `Array.some` is a good solution but it only returns a boolean, so a manual loop may be required here to grab the index

Comment: You can use `findIndex` with an appropriate function...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [indexOf method in an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is by getting the element through `.find()`, and then use the `.indexOf()`. for example:

```js
var member_data_list = [
  ["adrian", "test", Number(9)],
  ["supler", "test", Number(2.3)],
  ["franz", "test", Number(2.5)],
  ["drucker", "test", Number(9.6)],
];

if (exists(member_data_list, "franz")) {
    var found = member_data_list.find(row => row[0] === "franz")
    var index = member_data_list.indexOf(found)
    
    // if the element is exists then index's value will be greater than -1
    if (index > -1) {
      console.log("NAME IS IN ARRAY AT INDEX " + index)
    }
}
        
function exists(arr, search) {
   return arr.some(row => row.includes(search));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another function to get the index looping the array and using includes:

```js
var member_data_list = [
  ["adrian", "test", Number(9)],
  ["supler", "test", Number(2.3)],
  ["franz", "test", Number(2.5)],
  ["drucker", "test", Number(9.6)],
];

if (exists(member_data_list, "franz")) {
     var index = findIndex(member_data_list, 'franz'); 
     console.log("NAME IS IN ARRAY AT INDEX " + index);
}
        
function exists(arr, search) {
   return arr.some(row => row.includes(search));
}

function findIndex(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (array[i].includes(value)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array and return the index of the nested array. In order to find if that name is available in any child array use `includes` or `indexOf`. Also suppose the array contains two child array with some content then the higher index will be returned

```js
var member_data_list = [
  ["adrian", "test", Number(9)],
  ["supler", "test", Number(2.3)],
  ["franz", "test", Number(2.5)],
  ["drucker", "test", Number(9.6)],
];

function exists(arr, name) {
  let ind;
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.includes(name.toLowerCase())) {
      ind = index
    }
  })
  return ind;
}
let isExist = exists(member_data_list, "franz")
if (isExist) {
  console.log("NAME IS IN ARRAY AT INDEX " + isExist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (not working on Internet Explorer)

```js
var member_data_list = [
  ["adrian", "test", Number(9)],
  ["supler", "test", Number(2.3)],
  ["franz", "test", Number(2.5)],
  ["drucker", "test", Number(9.6)],
];

if (exists(member_data_list, "franz")) {
     var index = findIndex(member_data_list, 'franz'); 
     console.log("NAME IS IN ARRAY AT INDEX " + index);
}
        
function exists(arr, search) {
   return arr.some(row => row.includes(search));
}

function findIndex(arr, search) {
   return arr.findIndex(row => row.includes(search));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line:

```
var i = member_data_list.findIndex(item => item[0] ==="franz");
```

Run this online:

```js
var member_data_list = [
  ["adrian", "test", Number(9)],
  ["supler", "test", Number(2.3)],
  ["franz", "test", Number(2.5)],
  ["drucker", "test", Number(9.6)],
];

console.log(member_data_list.findIndex(item => item[0] ==="franz"));
```