# How can I use a component function in Vue to remove an object from an array in the parent's data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I think it's easier for you to just see the relevant VueJS code and then I can explain it:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        history: [
            {name: 'red', value: '#f00'},
            {name: 'not red', value: '#ff0'},
            {name: 'also not red', value: '#f0f'},
        ],
    },
    components: {
        ColorItem: {
            template:
                `<div>
                    <input :value="name">
                    <div class="color-preview" :style="{backgroundColor:hex}"></div>
                    <span v-html="hex"></span>
                    <button @click="$emit('remove')">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>`,
            props: 
                ['mode', 'hex', 'name'],
            methods: {
                removeColor: function(index) {
                    console.log(index);
                    this.history.splice(index, 1);
                }
            },
        }
    },
    // ...
}
```

I have objects (representing colors with names and values) in an array in a variable called `history` in my Vue app. I'm using `v-for` to create a new `color-item` component for each item in history:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in history" :key="item.value">
    <color-item mode="history" :name="item.name" :hex="item.value" @remove="removeColor(index)">
    </color-item>
</div>
```

I'm trying to delete the color from the list, and I saw [this beautiful example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-todomvc?from-embed) of how to use vue to remove items from a list, and it uses their position and splices it. I also saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008853/4907950) on getting the position using the map function, however `pos` is undefined for me, because `e.hex` is undefined, and using the inspector I think it's because Vue uses some sort of getter under the hood and doesn't just have the data there for me.

Before someone tells me to use the component template in the v-for loop, I need the template so I can reuse this for other lists of colors (for example, favorites).

I'm very new to Vue so pardon my improper wordings, and I appreciate all the help I can get learning this framework.

Answer (score 1):

The better approach here is to use `$emit` from the child component and listening to the event in the parent component.

You should pass `pos` as an event then change the `history` data directly in parent component

In your `removeColor` function:

```
this.$emit('remove-color', pos)
```

Then in parent component you should have:

```
<ColorItem v-on:remove-color="removeColorFromHistory" />
```

And change your data in methods of the parent component:

```js
methods: {
  removeColorFromHistory(pos) {
    this.history.splice(pos, 1);
  }
}
```

[(see documents)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event)

> $parent is meant for handling of edge cases, meaning unusual situations that sometimes require bending Vue’s rules a little. Note however, that they all have disadvantages or situations where they could be dangerous. [*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance)

Comment: How can I pass the `pos` position variable from my template? I have the component HTML defined in Vue using a template.

Comment: I updated my question using emit as suggested, however it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @Justin you have to have a template in the parent component where you listen to the event emited from the child `<ColorItem v-on:remove-color="METHOD" />` this will call the METHOD in the parent, your method is currently in the child component.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the child component should not be manipulating data of the parent component directly, especially via `this.$parent.whatever`. You should keep the boundaries of the components distinct, otherwise you'll make them tightly-coupled.

All the child component needs to do is emit a `remove` event that tells the parent that it should remove that item from its own data (which the parent owns).

In the child component:

```vue
<button @click="$emit('remove')">Remove</button>
```

Then in the parent component:

```vue
<div v-for="item of history">
  <color-item :hex="item.hex" @remove="removeItem(item)"/>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
  removeItem(item) {
    this.history = this.history.filter(otherItem => otherItem !== item)

    // or
    this.history.splice(this.history.indexOf(item), 1)
  }
}
```

The event handler for the `remove` event passes in the item to remove as an argument.

Since the parent component "owns" the `history` array, it should be the only component that mutates it. Once you start allowing random components to mutate data they do not own, then you start getting spaghetti code and it can be difficult to track down why a particular mutation happened and who mutated it.

Here is an example:

```js
Vue.component('color-item', {
  template: '#color-item',
  props: ['name', 'hex'],
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      { name: 'red', value: '#f00' },
      { name: 'green', value: '#0f0' },
      { name: 'blue', value: '#00f' },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    removeItem(item) {
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1)
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.name {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.preview {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="color-item">
  <div>
    <span class="name">{{ name }}</span>
    <div class="preview" :style="{ backgroundColor: hex }"></div>
    <button @click="$emit('remove')">Remove</button>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item of items">
    <color-item :name="item.name" :hex="item.value" @remove="removeItem(item)"></color-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I tried this and it didn't work; I believe it's something to do with needing the object's index in the array, whereas you're just treating the color items like primitives.

Comment: I tried passing in the index by using `v-for="(item, index) in history"` but it doesn't call the function

Comment: I'm not treating the color items like primitives. `item` is an object, no? This should work.

Comment: I think the function isn't called for some reason then... Could you look at my updated code?