# How can I edit a specific value from a json array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, edit

users.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rubs",
    "uuid": "9e24f3f5-7089-4f3c-bf63-211c24a0744e",
    "balance": 500
  },
  {
    "name": "Foxitic",
    "uuid": "39f6521c-5a18-48e4-8c84-6f1bb6c8de90",
    "balance": 500
  },
  {
    "name": "Jxsh",
    "uuid": "5f06ea31-3a20-43fc-8ce8-60ac7e7b0971",
    "balance": 500
  },
  {
    "name": "Bopeebo",
    "uuid": "91a5d15b-cca0-44e9-a513-91fe7ab05715",
    "balance": 500
  }
]
```

If I wanted to update the "balance" of an individual with the specified "name", how would I go about doing that?

I am already looping through each to find which object is the specified user's, I just need to be able to edit that object, and more specifically the balance. Thanks for all help you can give, you guys are the real heroes <3

Comment: You can do something like `foundObj.balance = 100`, which will update the found object (that you've obtained using your loop) to 100

Comment: How do you read the file? Are you familiar with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ?

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with Dinesh Patil's solution.
however, writing in arrow function makes the map() method a lot more easier to understand.

```
   const jsonObj = [
    {name: 'abc', balance: 400},
    {name: 'jkl', balance: 400},
    {name: 'erp', balance: 400}
   ]

   pos = jsonObj.map(val => val.name).indexOf('jkl')

   jsonObj[pos].balance = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

This link makes be useful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008853/10802524

Following ways can help you to achieve what you want.
**First**

- You can iterate a loop for each object.
- Add if condition to match the specific name.
- Finally, modify the balance of that index of the matched name.

```
const jsonObj = [{ name : "xyz", balance: 500},{ name : "abc", balance: 800},{ name : "efg", balance: 50}];

for(let obj of jsonObj){
If(obj.name === "abc")
     obj.balance = 700; // changing value for balance
}
```

**Second**

- You can use the map to get the index of a specific name.
- Modify the balance's value of that index.

```
const jsonObj = [{ name : "xyz", balance: 500},{ name : "abc", balance: 800},{ name : "efg", balance: 50}];

pos = jsonObj.map((obj)=> return obj.name;).indexOf('abc')

jsonObj[pos].balance = 700;
```

**Hope this will help you**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use forEach...
Use Arra.find https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find which skip the rest when something found...

yourArrry.find((el)=>el.name == nameToFind).balance = newBalance;

You can store return value of find in a variable and assign new value after verifying when it is not undefined

Answer (score 0):

Suggest the idea like this.

- you have to know the 'name' (ie. 'Jxsh') you want to update the balance.
- then find out an index of that name in the users array (ie. index = 2).
- use that index (ie. users[2]) to update the balance to amount you want (ie. users[2].balabce=900 ).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I would do something like this:

```
let ids = {};    
let arr = [
    {
        "name": "Rubs",
        "uuid": "9e24f3f5-7089-4f3c-bf63-211c24a0744e",
        "balance": 500
    },
    {
        "name": "Foxitic",
        "uuid": "39f6521c-5a18-48e4-8c84-6f1bb6c8de90",
        "balance": 500
    },
    {
        "name": "Jxsh",
        "uuid": "5f06ea31-3a20-43fc-8ce8-60ac7e7b0971",
        "balance": 500
    },
    {
        "name": "Bopeebo",
        "uuid": "91a5d15b-cca0-44e9-a513-91fe7ab05715",
        "balance": 500
    }
  ]
    arr.map((item, index) => {ids[item.uuid] = index});

    ////update balance code
    arr[ids["91a5d15b-cca0-44e9-a513-91fe7ab05715"]].balance = 333;
```