# How to improve the performance of 'for loop' to integrate some objects in JS

Tags: javascript

I have three for loop as below to integrate their objects.
The problem is the length of 'cars' array is 20,000.
So it should runs every 20,000 times for finding same id between company.user and cars.
But the id of cars is unique.
Can I reduce this repeat number in JS?
I want to reduce the taking time.
Thank you for reading it.
p.s. I uploaded same question adding the concrete logic inside of for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < company.length; i += 1) {
  for (let j = 0; j < company[i].user.length; j += 1) {
    for (let k = 0; k < cars.length; k += 1) {
      if (company[i].user[j].id === cars[k].id) {
        company[i].user[j] = {
          ...company[i].user[j],
          ...cars[k] 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have multiple `company.user` and `cars` or is there only 1 match?

Comment: @Ifaruki It matches with only one thing..

Comment: if its possible, you could sort the "cars" array and then use some search algorithms to reduce the search time. Everyhing you need to know about search algorithms you can find here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-algorithms/

Comment: Don't check the length in the for loop, store the length and check against the stored value instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452317/do-loops-check-the-array-length-every-time-when-comparing-i-against-array-length

Comment: @ThomasJason did the break improved something?

Comment: @Ifaruki Nope. I think it breaks just after matching once. I try to use binary search now. You gived me a inspiration.

Comment: @ThomasJason you sure that it breaks? because there is no break

Comment: for a given user.id, can the number of number of cars with the same id be **greater than 1** ?

Comment: Make indexes out of plain objects or Map instances so that you can directly look up a car or user by id.

Comment: Also it would probably be better to avoid creating new objects for each user, and instead just `Object.assign()` the car properties to the existing user object.

Comment: what is the type of cars.id ? are they unique ?

Comment: are `cars.id` in ascendent order ?

Comment: is there always only one car.id for each user.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only 1 match then use `break` after you found that item. Imagine you find that item at index 1 for example, then the loop would still continue and do 19998 loops. Because of the information that you know there is only 1 possible match you can break it there.

```
    if (company[i].user[j].id === cars[k].id) {
      company[i].user[j] = {
        ...company[i].user[j],
        ...cars[k] 
      }
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (let i = 0, leni = company.length;; i < leni ; i += 1) {
    for (let j = 0, lenj = company[i].user.length; j < lenj; j += 1) {
      for (let k = 0, lenk = cars.length; k < lenk; k += 1) {
        if (company[i].user[j].id === cars[k].id) {
          company[i].user[j] = {
            ...company[i].user[j],
            ...cars[k] 
          }
          break; // match only the first one, then stop searching for cars
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer based on test results from https://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4

Spread left in base on

https://thecodebarbarian.com/object-assign-vs-object-spread.html

[image]

Comment: `throw in an empty object`   but `company[i].user[j]` is not empty...

Answer (score 0):

this will optimize your code a little more, but **ziga1337** is right, the only effective way is to sort your two objects

```
// company: [ { user: [ { id: '?1' 
// cars: [ { id: '?2' 

for (let iCompagny of compagny) {
  for (let iUser of iCompagny.user) {
    let fCar = cars.find(xCar.id===iUser.id)
    if (fCar) Object.assign(iUser, fCar)
  }
}
```

> in case there is always a car.id unique to each user.id:

```
let indexCars = cars.reduce((a,c)=>{ a[c.id]=c; return a },{})

compagny.forEach(iCompagny=>{
  iCompagny.user.forEach(iUser=>{ Object.assign(iUser, indexCars[iUser.id]) })
})
```