# Decrementing While Loop ordering Javascript

Tags: javascript

this is actually my first post about javascript. Would like to know, the performance of the following code as it is a "Decrementing while loop" inside that while loop has an Incrementing variable.

```
var i = data.d.length;
var i_counter=0;


while (i--)
{
   console.log(i_counter++)
}
```

My reason for adding i_counter++ is for sorting purposes. Would it slightly affect the loops performance for thousand of records? Would this code below much better than aboves performance?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
   console.log(i)
}
```

I have seen an online loop stress test online and this shows that decrementing while is the best. 
Is it true? http://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/32
Please give me a fiddle to stress test the code. Thank you. Suggestions are well accepted.

Comment: There is no "performance" issue. For all practical purposes they take the same amount of work: use the form that is most clear.

Comment: Hi, suggestion well appreciated, can you provide me a sample fiddle about stress testing about my code? Thanks,

Comment: The only slow operation we can see is the console.log. *That* is costly. Decrementing or incrementing isn't.

Comment: So my code provided above is still much more faster than this code?for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {}

Comment: @user3932204 No. It is "about the same speed" for all practical purposes, even with two additional property lookups. Create a microbenchmark if you like: http://jsperf.com

Comment: No : it takes about the same time. The standard `for` loop in the increment direction is optimized. You could try to profile that using [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) but you'd mostly see measuring artifacts, it's not worth the pain.

Comment: You're on the wrong path. That's *not* where your program needs optimization. You should really **profile** to find the hot spots before even trying to do this kind of optimizations.

Comment: I've been struggling to find what is the best and fastest loop over the internet most I see was using decrementing while loop. Now you are pointing out the standard for loop as the optimized and fastest? I am confused now, just a newbie :(.. learning coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the runtime is by magnitudes dominated by `console.log`, which performs potentially blocking IO (log functions are in general not cheap, in particular when they produce visible console/UI output).

Assuming `console.log` a no-op, the first code should have a slight advantage since `d.length` is not re-evaluated every iteration (which is two dictionary lookups in the unoptimized case). A very intelligent JS runtime may be able to avoid this out even for the second case, though.

The best advice is, to optimize **last** and **only** after profiling which parts of your code are actual bottlenecks. FF and Chrome have profiling tools built-in for this purpose.

For the perfect JS loop iteration, have a look at [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349425/whats-the-fastest-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript). Doing an extra increment on every iteration should not dramatically affect things.

Comment: Thank you but, sorry, please disregard the console.log.