# search a word in array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that consists of several words and I am finding a particular word. My current solution, which is below, works perfectly fine for small array. But if this array contains lets say 10,000 words then my solution would require a lot memory and CPU resources as it is not efficient enough. **How can I make my code better in terms of performance and should take less resources for a large array in JavaScript?**

```
var words = ['apple', 'orange', 'ananas', 'banana', 'mango', 'lemon', 'tomato'];

function search (term) {
  for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (words[i] === term) {
      console.log(words[i] + ' is found at ' + i);
    }
  }
}

search('tomato');
```

Comment: Can you modify the word array? In particular, sort it?

Comment: If it is a sorted array, you could do a binary search.

Comment: Both sorted and unsorted solution.

Comment: Array has `indexOf()` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepopulate a dictionary (object) with the words as keys. Then a lookup is merely `dict[term]`.

```
var words = ['apple', 'orange', 'ananas', 'banana', 'mango', 'lemon', 'tomato'];
var dict = {};

function prepopulate() {
    words.forEach(function(word, i) { dict[word] = i; });
}

function search (term) {
    if (term in dict) {
        console.log(term + ' is found at ' + dict[term]);
    }
}

prepopulate();
search('tomato');
```

Comment: Could you also give us time complexity of this solution?

Comment: Depends on the engine's algorithms, but I'm guessing that the time for pre-population is O(n), and the time for lookup is around O(1) or slightly worse.

Comment: I am looking for O(log n) or something better. But your solution could be the one that I could use. Could you make it a bit better?

Comment: It **is** better than O(log n), it's O(1). The prepopulation is a one-time cost amortized over many lookups.

Comment: But O(n) is not better.

Comment: O(n) happens **once** and once only. It's a minor investment which serves to vastly reduce the time for your actual lookups, which I assume you are going to do many times.

Answer (score 2):

Well, don't know if I'm missing something but why can't you use `indexOf`?

```
function search (term) {
   console.log(term + " is found at " + words.indexOf(term));
}
```

Comment: IndexOf uses bruteforce algorithm that means its time complexity would be O(n2).

Comment: @2619 It's native and fast and will be definitely faster than looping and finding as it's built-in. You're using something similar I suppose

Comment: I am using similar that is why I am looking for better solution but indexOf definitely not the solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the consensus answer is that the fastest way to iterate through an array is [with the very same `for` loop that you used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349425/whats-the-fastest-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript), so nice work.  But, I [made a jsPerf for this specific case](http://jsperf.com/fastest-word-from-array), and...

It turns out the `while` loop is quicker!  In fact, it seems to be a whole 90% quicker.  Not sure why that's the case, but the proof is all there (at least in my browser).  Granted, I assumed that if you had multiple instances of the value in the array, you would want to know *all* the indices that matched it, not just the first occurrence, so the return value is an array as well.  Anyway, here is the winning code block:

```
//Note that I have 2 instances of tomato!
var words = ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'ananas', 'banana', 'mango', 'lemon', 'tomato'];

//Gave the function two arguments to make it more generic
function search (arr, term) {
  var i, indices = [];
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] === term) {
      indices.push(i);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return indices;
}

search(words, 'tomato');
```