# HOW TO LOOP HTML ELEMENTS WITHOUT USING forEach()?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, htmlelements

I'm currently working with my web based system using nodejs and html.

Is there any alternative way to loop html elements without using forEach?

I'm thinking about like this(this is just an example):

```
 <% for(var ctr=0; ctr<arrayname.length;ctr++){ %>`
      `<input type="text">`
    `<%}%>`
```

I hope someone will answer my question. :)

Comment: have you tried using jstl tags?

Comment: What's wrong with using foreach

Comment: you can use for loops, which are faster.

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349425/whats-the-fastest-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: @chiliNUT ill be needing the 'ctr' variable and its value for some purposes.

Comment: @dandavis how can i do that? ive been searching in google for hours but it seems there's no example of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your issue is that you need to be access your iterating variable, which is workable through a `.forEach` call as the *second* argument in the function provided to the `.forEach` call.

Code below to show proof.

```js
$(function(){
  var items = ['one','two','three'];
  items.forEach(function(item,ctr){
    $('#testing').append('<div class="ctr-'+ctr+'">'+item+' CTR: '+ctr+'</div>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to iterate through 'iterables' in javascript as in any other language.

Please take a look to this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Here you will find examples of all the possible ways:

- for statement
- do...while statement
- while statement
- labeled statement
- break statement
- continue statement
- for...in statement
- for...of statement

I hope it helps. If it doesn't fit you, it would be nice to know what and why you want to achieve.