# What is the fastest way to scan a JS array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, search, authentication

I am making a local login using JavaScript and I need to know the fastest way to scan an array.

Say there are two arrays:

```
usernames = ["uname 1", "uname 2", "uname 3"];
passwords = ["pswd 1", "pswd 2", "pswd 3"];
```

And there are two HTML inputs

```
<input id="username">
<input id="password">
```

I need to know the fastest way to see if the value from the HTML inputs matches any username and password.

I have tried a while function:

```
while(counter1 < usernames.length){
   //testing goes here
   counter ++;
}
```

And an "if / repeate" function

```
if(counter1 < usernames.length){
    //testing goes here
    setTimeout(currentFunction, 1);
}
```

This is not a duplicate of the question "What's the fastest way to loop through an array in JavaScript?" because I am open to more than a

```
for
```

loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to loop through an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349425/whats-the-fastest-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Could you elaborate why it has to be "the fastest"? Would a difference between 10ms and 100ms matter for your application?

Comment: @georg: More like 10ns and 100ns. :-)

Comment: Yes, the difference between 10ms and 100ms does matter, I do not want people on my login to have to wait any longer than they should.

Comment: This is not a copy of "What's the fastest way to loop through an array in JavaScript?" because of the fact that I am open to more than just a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "the fastest" to matter, I assume there must be a lot of entries in the array — like, millions. If so, I'd definitely offload to native code by using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (if all you need to know is *whether* there's a match). Otherwise, really, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this allows me to get what I need almost instantly.