# Count number of object in my array with a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

I have an array of objects that looks similar to this one:

```
const myArray = [
    {
        message: "foo",
        seen: false
    },
    {
        message: "bar",
        seen: false
    },
    {
        message: "foobar"
        seen: true
    }
];
```

I would like to count the number of object in my array where the `seen` property is set to `false`.

I know how to do it with a classic For loop but I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way to do so ?

Thank you, any help much appreciated.

EDIT: Here are my codes with for loops

```
var count = 0;
    for (var x in myArray) {
        if(!x.seen) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

and

```
    var count = 0;
    myArray.forEach(e => {
        if(!e.seen) {
            count++;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Show us your effort first...

Comment: There is plenty of ways to do this, what have you tried?

Comment: I have done it using a For loop and the forEach method but I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this

Comment: @nsayer Post your code as well.

Comment: @WisnuAdiNurcahyo I have updated with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `filter`.

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    message: "foo",
    seen: false,
  },
  {
    message: "bar",
    seen: false,
  },
  {
    message: "foobar",
    seen: true,
  },
];

const result = myArray.filter(x => !x.seen).length;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105977/6192621

The fastest way is the reverse simple loop.

```
for(i = myArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) if(!myArray[i].seen) count++;
```