# How to loop the jquery call more effectively instead of looping multiple times

Tags: jquery, performance

Using the below piece of logic we are trying to loop the records which are in DB suppose if I have 1000 rows then it is getting iterated 1000 times where it is taking more time instead of doing this how can I make it simpler and achieve the results quickly

```
 for (var row in db) {
            if (db.hasOwnProperty(row)) {
                if (currentid == db[row].actualid)
                    optionsHtmlString += '<option value="' + db[row].MemberId + '" selected="selected" title="' + db[row].FullName + '">' + db[row].FullName + '</option>';
                else
                    optionsHtmlString += '<option value="' + db[row].MemberId + '" title="' + db[row].FullName + '">' + db[row].FullName + '</option>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, you can make it simpler by using `for (var row of db) { ... }` without the `hasOwnProperty` check. I would say that using a `select` with 1000s of rows is not the greatest user experience...

Comment: You could potentially use `map()` to build the strings to be appended, but however you approach this you're not going to see much benefit as the logic flow is the same, ie. loop, concatenate, append. If you're seeing performance issues with 1000 options. Then I'd suggest you instead move the logic to the server side, using an AJAX powered auto-complete field.

Comment: You could build the HTML server-side (eg in a partial view using ASP.Net-MVC) which will generally be quicker, depending on the server specs of course.

Comment: hasownproperty check is mandatory

Comment: it should be handled client side can i use foreach

Comment: Like @RoryMcCrossan suggested, you better choose an auto-complete method as an alternative. Because even if you optimize your JS code, or generate it (hard-coded DOM) via your server, the browser will try to render a long list of options and the user will get lost among them :) If the DB data is not frequently updated, and the query is the same (not different combinations of filters or parameters) , you could store it in a static json.. And use it with Ajax autocomplete. Less extra DB queries too ;)

Comment: how can i implement that

Comment: I can't imagine that a user wants to search trough 1000 entries. Why don't you make it dynamically. Just return first 100 results if no search character is set. On typing in the search field do a new db request and update the results

Comment: but it is not smart search it is a drop down which needs to fetch all the members

Comment: can i use a foreach loop instead of for oop if i use foreach then how can i validate db.hasownproperty(true) condition

Comment: *"it is not smart search it is a drop down"* - the suggestions are to *make* it a "smart search"

Comment: Any other type of `for` (`for(var i;i<length;++i)` / `for..in` / `for..of` / `.map` / `while`) will still essentially be looping through each DB item one at a time and will not have significant performance improvements over 1000 rows (maybe a few ms over 10million rows...).  Here's on old question that might be relevant (see how many rows it attempts to get a minor difference) https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252102/2181514

Comment: Take a look at select2.org. this might be what you want to have

Comment: could any one please help me with sample logic to achieve this performance issue

Comment: No, because your concept is wrong. But you won’t accept this event if 100 people will tell you.