# How to optimize big array comparision

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on one Reactjs project- where i have cities and areas of each city ,in each city it may have more the 200 areas . Each area is having 3 attributes `cityId,AreaID ,isAdded,`. And city is have one attribute `cityId`.

Here i need to store Areas of each city in a separate array.How can i optimize this operation

```
export const getAreas = (cityID,allAreas) => {
  try {
    let areas = [];
    if (allAreas) {
     allAreas?.forEach((area) => {
        if (area?.cityID === cityID) {
          areas.push(area);
        }
      });
      return areas;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: What is this try catch used for when there is no place that can throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const areasPerCity = new Map();
allAreas.forEach((area) => {
  if (!areasPerCity.get(area.cityId)) {
    areasPerCity.set(area.cityId, []);
  }
  areasPerCity.get(area.cityId).push(area);
});
return areasPerCity; 
// here, you have a Map of a city ID => array of areas
// you could use it like `const areas = areasPerCity.get(cityId);`
```

Complexity is O(n) with one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useMemo hook. it can memorise your returned value.

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usememo.asp

Answer (score -1):

If by optimise you mean wanted to shorten your provided snippet, the below is a shorter version of your example. The [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array method works great here for filtering down your initial array.

```
const getAreas = (cityID, allAreas) => allAreas.filter((area) => area.cityID === cityID)
```

Although this isn't much faster if you were looking to optimise for algorithm speed. If you want to improve this, the answers found here ["What's the fastest way to loop through an array in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349425/whats-the-fastest-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript) might help you speed up the loop which will have the biggest impact on performance.

Comment: The question was about optimization, not to shrink the operation.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest JavaScript iteration by FAR is the basic for loop, so something like this would be much faster:

```
export const getAreas = (cityID,allAreas) => {
  try {
    let areas = [];
    if (allAreas) {
     for(let area = 0; area < allAreas.length; area++){
        if (allAreas[area].cityID === cityID) {
          areas.push(allAreas[area]);
        }
      });
      return areas;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```