# How do I minify CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any recommendations for a CSS minifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier)

How do I minify my css and javascript scripts? Also would it be better to reference jquery stored on Google's server or my own?

Comment: Both of these questions have already been answered by Google, and possibly, this site.

Comment: Duplicated question. See resources below in SO site: - [Javascript minifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1737388/881286)
- [CSS minifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/787789/881286) Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Also try searching first, all of these topics have been *thoroughly* covered here already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) & [minify tool](http://www.minifycss.com/)