# How to use GZIP?

Tags: gzip

I am new at using GZIP.

I'm using a Wordpress plugin that GZIP the website but I ran the Google Speed test and it says that the website is not gzipping bootstrap .less files and the javascript files that I call.

I'm not sure how to call a gzip or even making one, can somebody help me?

Comment: You should setup your webserver to do that for you on your static content.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the plugin that you are using?

Comment: The Plugin I'm using is this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-gzip-compression/ ... @driis How can I do that? I'm having problems setting my static content to as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904930/cookie-free-domain-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript should be served minified and after minification both JS and CSS should be served compressed. Have a look at [How to 'minify' Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737388/how-to-minify-javascript-code)

Comment: I know how to minify JS I just dont know how to compress it to one file and call it to work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache 2.* as your web server you could enable `mod_deflate`. You can then configure the module to compress `.less` and any other static content you want to compress.

Here is a link to the documentation for the module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: When I copy the code and put it on .htaccess I get error 500 :/

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira Did you load the module in the `httpd.conf` file?