# Cookie Free Domain Doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cookies, subdomain

I was following this tutorial: http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/07/wordpress-cookie-free-domain/

So, I created (CPANEL) the subdomain static.artswr.com and redirected it to artswr.com/wp-content/

I edited and add the following in the end of the wp-config file:

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.artswr.com");
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.artswr.com");
```

I am loading everything with `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` but its not working, also I'm getting 404 errors when I try to find a file in static.artswr.com

Comment: Probably better on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com or maybe http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.artswr.com");
```

Try

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.artswr.com/wp-content");
```

without any redirections from your cpanel. `static.artswr.com` should point to `artswr.com`

Answer (score 0):

check below line:
So, I created (CPANEL) the subdomain static.artswr.com and redirected it to artswr.com/wp-content/

You mentioned that you have redirected, but it should not be redirect, It should map to wp-content folder.
Let me know if any comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I do that?

Comment: I searched for that info and what I've found was related with CNAME, is that correct? Thank you