# Click issue if button has childs

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

I've:

```
backdrop = document.getElementById('backdrop');
dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
dialog_body = document.querySelector('#dialog .body');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if ( matches.call(e.target, '[data-show=dialog]')) {
    buoy.addClass(backdrop, 'fadeIn');
    buoy.addClass(dialog, 'fadeIn');
    var href = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('action');
    dialog_body.innerHTML = '<div>FOOOOO</div>';
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-hide=dialog]'), function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        buoy.removeClass(backdrop, 'fadeIn');
        buoy.removeClass(dialog, 'fadeIn');
      })
    })
}
```

}, false);

and [data-show=dialog] is:

```
<button type="sumit" class="btn xs default" data-show="dialog">
    <i class="ellipsis-v"></i>
</button>
```

If I click on

```
<i class="ellipsis-v"></i>
```

the code doesn't work..

If I click out of

```
<i class="ellipsis-v"></i>
```

the code works perfectly..

Also if I have:

```
<button type="sumit" class="btn xs default" data-show="dialog">
    <i class="ellipsis-v"></i>
    <span>fooo</span>
</button>
```

If I click on

```
<i class="ellipsis-v"></i>
```

or

```
<span>fooo</span>
```

the code doesn't work..

If I click out of

```
<i class="ellipsis-v"></i>
```

or

```
span>fooo</span>
```

the code works perfectly..

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Why Not:**

```
function handler(e){
 var t=e.target;
 if(t.dataset['show']=='dialog'||t.parentNode.dataset['show']=='dialog'){
  /* code ...... */ 
 }
}
document.addEventListener('click',handler,false);
```

in this case you have one eventHandler.(no loops).

you can add that handler to the parentNode for simplicity.

and you have to add a better check for `t.dataset['show']=='dialog'` as it produces an error if it has no dataset. (i wrote it just to give you an idea)

btw you search for `data-hide` but you have only `data-show`

if you have any questions just ask..

if i misunderstood your question tell me so i can reelaborate the code.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/A7xk2/1/

Less eventHadlers is always more performance...

also in this example i'm just writing now... i need alot of mouse events and most of them are on the document itself...

http://jsfiddle.net/LxX34/12/

**EDIT**

Add the click handler on the btn elements

it works on span on li and on button as you can see in this example.

maybe your li has some sort of `preventDefault` or return `false`??

http://jsfiddle.net/A7xk2/2/

Comment: The problem is I want when I click <span> or <i> javascript consider <button> is clicked, not <i> or <span>......My eventHendler starts only if I click on <button> and not in its childs......With jquery I've not this problem...

Comment: create a jsfiddle so i see better whats the problem.. anyway i have to go now for 10min.. but if you do so i'm happy to help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: don't use forEach & call it has a bad performance.also queryselector. use classname or id

Comment: I use queryselector and foreach cause ajax calls.......ther's another way? I've post my entire code......

Comment: who wrote that code? there are much simpler ways to write that mess. 'matches.call(e.target, '[data-show=dialog]')' ??? .. tell me in simple words like 'i want to fade in every element from ajax' what you wanna do and i show you how.

Comment: var matches;
(function(doc) {
   matches = 
      doc.matchesSelector ||
      doc.webkitMatchesSelector ||
      doc.mozMatchesSelector ||
      doc.oMatchesSelector ||
      doc.msMatchesSelector;
})(document.documentElement);
for matches function...

Comment: juse because there is a new api for it does not mean it's better.. most of the time it's slower (it should be simpler) but that one is useless.

Comment: your using  library for compatibility reasons?? in that case you should use every comand from that library. the first thing i see is that you use 'e.target' which would break the compatiblity. as older firefox don't support e.target.. also ie not

Comment: if you just want to be compatible with modern browsers ... all new ones including ie10,ios and android .. i suggest you use standard javascript.

Comment: Ok.....
I've ajax call that populate the page with divs and their [data-show=dialog].....
I've to add ".fadeIn" class to #backdrop and #dialog when I click on [data-show=dialog] elements that are calles via ajax...
and #backdrop has [data-hide=dialog] for remove ".fadeIn" class from #backdrop and #dialog.
#backdrop and #dialog are static elements of the page.
My original problem was simple: when I click on button that has [data-show=dialog], if I click on button icon or span it doesn't work, but if I click on button pudding that is not icon or span it doesn't.

You're very gentle man...

Comment: I'm interested for compatibility from IE9, FF 24, and all recent..
I've decided to traduced my jquery in vanilla and I'm in trouble..

Comment: mh yeah actually ie9 and ff24 are a big problem.. srsly if you read the caniuse.com site you will notice that both properly work only in the latest versions. and even if i hate to say that then you should use jquery.(i don't use it) especially if you use ajax.

Comment: and then add those eventhandlers with jquery. because for example e.target in ff24 = e=e||window.event;e.target=e.target||e.srcElement.. and so on...

Comment: .. so.. to go back to you base problem: http://jsfiddle.net/A7xk2/2/ in this example you can see how i add the click handlers . and also that clicking on the i element works. that means that your i element has something that stops from bubbling.

Comment: IE 9 and FF 24 are used by a lot of people.....right? 
But I want have vanilla js for performance reasons....right?
I've found yet a good code for ajax calls...

Comment: vanilla // pure js is cool but you need to learn the basics first .. don't use all this new apis like foreach call matches ... whatever ... you should use simple for loops while getElementByClassName ect... those are much much faster than the new ones. the new ones are just for some special occasions if nothing else can help.

Comment: If you're available in a month you could translate my jquery in vanilla......As a Work.....right?
What about that?
Can you give me an email?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18309057/2450730 this is the ajax function i use for everything.Pure js - Simple & short.

Comment: no i do it for fun .... i don't work with it. but i can help you.Read some fome of my answers... they are all in PURE JS.. i hate jquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21353032/2450730 .. if i write a function i rewrite everithing so many times until no compressor can compress my code.

Comment: function load(url, from, to) {
    var cached=sessionStorage[url];
    if(!from){from="body";} // default to grabbing body tag
    if(to && to.split){to=document.querySelector(to);}
    if(!to){to=document.querySelector(from);} // default re-using the source elm as the target elm
    var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest; // new ajax
    XHRt.responseType='document';  // ajax2 context and onload() event
    XHRt.onload= function() { sessionStorage[url]=to.innerHTML= XHRt.response.querySelector(from).innerHTML;};
    XHRt.open("POST", url, true);
    XHRt.send();
    return XHRt;
}
This is my ajax..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46431/discussion-between-niser-and-cocco)