# How to structure source code so that it takes less space?

Tags: javascript

I am learning from stackoverflow and getting lot of solutions. When I study it I found that .js file has no structured like :

```
function MSIsPlayback()
{
    try
    {
        return parent&&parent.WebPlayer
    }
    catch(d)
    {
        return!1
    }
}
```

but they wrote this in one line like ,

```
use strict';window.StackExchange={};function MSIsPlayback(){try{return parent&&parent.WebPlayer}catch(d){return!1}}if(!MSIsPlayback()&&top!=self)throw top.location.replace(document.location),$(function()$("head").add("body").remove()}),alert("For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames."),Error();
```

why?

Is programmer wrote it? or any software converted it in this pattern like after compilation? if they wrong then how then debug it?

please help 
thanks

Comment: it is the minimised version(the filesize is small). so that it can be download easily in slower internet connections.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with jQuery...

Comment: Oh, that is not jQuery. you mean, JavaScript. jQuery is one of the Library written in JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'minify' Javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737388/how-to-minify-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0):

that is minified js file.
typically, you should minify your js file when you release that, in order to reduce load time.

you can fined uncompressed jquery source code [here](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: can you tell me how to minified js file and how to convert reverse in

Comment: you can use uglifyjs, closure compiler, or YUI compressor to minify javascript file. and basically, you cannot  fully unminify minified js file, since minifying process basically change variable's name to reduce file size. but you can reformat code by using [jsbeautifier]( http://jsbeautifier.org/) or chrome developer tool(click source tab, chose js file you want, then click `{}` icon at the left)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of doing is called as **minifying** of code, This process will be done once the code is fully tested and ready for the production. This process involves *removal of unnecessary spaces, and giving a shorter variable, function name* etc..

The main reason for **minifying** the code is to improve the *loading time* of a website.

Comment: Don't  format text as code that isn't code. If you want highlight text, you can make it *italic* or **bold**.