# javascript image loop not working

Tags: javascript

i dont know what to do as i am noob at javascript as i have just started learning today, so please go easy.

i think i need to increment it when it does an interval but i don't know how to do that and as well i dont want to do any jquery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                height: 300px;
                width: 500px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <img id="image" src="html.png" alt="HTML">
        </div>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            var i = 1;

            function loop() {
                var i = i + 1;
                if (i == 3) {
                    i = 1;
                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('image').src = "html.png";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('image').src = "css3.png";
                }
            }
            var pictureloop = setInterval(loop(), 5000);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing, Why you're declaring `var i` in loop again? just initialize it with `i=`

Comment: like i said im noob at this i thought i had to do that

Comment: setInterval expect a function as first argument (you're giving it the result of loop -> nothing). So remove the `()` ;)

Comment: thanks guys just got it working it was me being a noob like usual :)

Comment: @user3323986 This is your first question, so, this is not so usual. Welcome on SO :D

Comment: thank you, you procrastinator :D

Comment: @Tom Also check : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to try this:

Just set variable `i` in you `loop()` no need to re-declare once it's globally declared! and
remove `()` from the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) method

```
var i = 1;

function loop() {
    i = i + 1; // Change
    alert(i);
    if (i == 3) {
        i = 1;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        document.getElementById('image').src = "html.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('image').src = "css3.png";
    }
}
setInterval(loop, 5000); //Change
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DGGaY/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove the global declaration and move it to the inner scope, since he only uses it there? global declarations are intended for cross-function variables, not local variables.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Yeah it would be better if he declares it locally! As i've just guided OP not to declare a same variable 2 times whether it is set to local or global :)

Answer (score 0):

**You just started learning javascript??**

welcome ;)

```
function loop(){
 i=++i==3?1:i;
 //i is : if i+1 is 3 then 1 else its i (the already i+1)

 document.getElementById('image').src=(i==1?'html':'css3')+'.png';
 //src is : if i is 1 then html else css3

}
var pictureloop=setInterval(loop,1000),i=1;
//set all vars you need separated by comma.
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/9dZt6/1/

proper way

```
function loop(){
 i=!i;
 document.body.innerHTML=(i?'html':'css3')+'.png'
}
var pictureloop=setInterval(loop,1000),i=1;
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/cRn6n/

**another way : html5 css3**

css

```
div{
 background:#000 url(html.png) no-repeat center center;
 background-size:contain;// cover,auto,100px 100px 
}
div.odd{
 background-image:url(css3.png);
}
```

js

```
function toggle(){
 var div1=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
 div1.classList.toggle('odd');
 timer=window.setTimeout(toggle,1e3);
}
var timer=window.setTimeout(toggle,1e3);
```

**another way : check the path**

```
function toggle(){
 img.src=(img.src=='http://path/html.png'?'css3':'html')+'.png';
}
var img=document.getElementById('image'),
    timer=window.setInterval(toggle,1e3);
```

+1 for not using jquery

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21353032/2450730

if you have any questions just ask.