# How to Bundle javascript file without using npm or nodejs? [ Standalone javascript bundler ]

Tags: javascript, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I am working on a project and I am not using any nodejs or npm package, But in the Production site, I want to upload the "bundled and minified javascript" file.

Is there any way to bundle a javascript file without using npm or nodejs?

**update:** I am using `Apache` as a web-server. It's a simple static website, but I have 5 JS files. I want to bundle them all in one just like how webpack does with the bundling of all files and combining them all in one with minification.

Thanks

Comment: how will you be serving your pages? sure you can build html pages and bring in your links for CSS/JS pages and serve them directly from github or even Heroku for that matter, having said that I think it's best you clarify your question if that's not what you're looking to do.

Comment: I will be serving file from Apache

Comment: Why don't you want node package manager (npm)? This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737388/how-to-minify-javascript-code

Comment: npm is just overburdened for small sites and I don't use node or npm. Thank you for the link, I am looking around it.

Cheers